# Spring Security Custom freemarker form

Tags: spring-security, freemarker

I'm currently working on a project were we use freemarker as a template language.
Instead of using the defualt login form I have created a custom controller and a custom freemarker view which goes along with that controller

Code:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
private static finaal String LOGIN = "components/security/login";

@RequestMapping("/security/login")
public String login(){

    return LOGIN;
   }
}
```

my freemarker template:

HTML Code:

```
<form action="${rc.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="j_username"><br/>
    <label for="password">Password</label><input type="text" id="password" name="j_password"><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login!">
</form>
```

my applicationContext-security.xml

```
  <http>
    <logout/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_GUEST"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/login" filters="none"/>
        <form-login login-page="/security/login" />
    </http>
```

the login works like a charm BUT, when a user enters a wrong username or password no error messages are shown and I can't figure out how to do it. Could you please help me with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code for those who wonder how i did it:

```
<#if Session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION?? && Session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message?has_content>
    <@spring.message "login.bad.credentials"/>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the error page:

```
<http>
   ...
   <form-login authentication-failure-url="/loginError.jsp" default-target-url="/start.jsp" />
   ...
</http>
```

In **loginError.jsp**:

```
...
Login error. Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>.
...
```

Comment: Thanks but to specify a new page wasn't necessary, but your hint
with SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message made me think. Thank you